How to update react state from loop of promises
I have a real world problem:

service exists to upload files one-by-one

(say, due to limitation of WebDav storage)


upload files one-by-one from PC
update UI list of uploaded files gradually

Something like this emulation:
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: "Marry" },
  { id: 2, name: "had" },
  { id: 3, name: "a" },
  { id: 4, name: "little" },
  { id: 5, name: "lamb" },
];

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={uploadItems}>Upload items</button>
      <ul>
          {items.map((itm) => (
            <li>{itm.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
    </div>
  );

  /*** Private ***/

  function uploadItems() {
    const ids = data.map((itm) => itm.id)

    ids.forEach((id) =>
      doUpload(id).then(async (itm) => {
        setItems(items.concat(itm));
        await delay(); // This doesn't work
      })
    );
  }
}

/*** Private ***/

function doUpload(id) {
  const timeout = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve(data.find((itm) => itm.id === id)), timeout)
  );
}

function delay() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
}

So the problem is that items array is empty on each iteration within promise callback (which supposed to be "appended").
Thus setItems results on setting an array with only one item from the promise.
(I've tried to hack it with "delay" but without success)
(Here is the working sandbox)

You're using concat, which is meant to merge two arrays, but itm is not an array, but an object, which causes it to be overwritten. I think what you want is push instead of concat.

It's not quite clear what you're asking here. Do you have a problem with the loop not working one-by-one? Does the state not update as expected? What exactly is expected? What does the state represent, the items to be uploaded or the results you got back from the upload or something else?

concat works with single items as well. and it returns a "copy" of array


Does the state not update as expected?

Yes, the state value items always comes empty on every iteration.
Which should not be the case, since it is being "appended" each time.
I guess it's a renown react's "batching" logic/issue which doesn't update state immediately.
So the question is: how to overcome this ?
(I've updated description respectively)

The question was mistakenly closed to me. The "duplicate" issue is about async handling within the loop and has nothing to do with the react... (And if the hint is to change .forEach() to "for ... of", then it doesn't work either; not speaking of the fact it will make server calls sequential, if to be awaited after each iteration)

"if the hint is to change .forEach() to "for ... of", then it doesn't work either" - yes, that is the most obvious problem the code has. Don't use forEach if you want the uploads to happen one-by-one. Just for (const requestItem of data) { const responseItem = await doUpload(requestItem.id); setItems(…); }. You don't need any sort of await delay(); // This doesn't work.

"So the problem is that items array is empty on each iteration" - ah, yes, that's another problem. It's the typical stale closure problem. To avoid it use the updater callback syntax: setItems(items => [...items, responseItem]);. I've updated the list of duplicates.

Bingo. Yes, "updater function" is the solution. Thank you.
(And btw no need to await on every iteration, since it will defeat the purpose of parallel service requests).
(It can be considered as dup of stale closure problem indeed)

(And in fact forEach works as well with updater function)
